# Microsoft Solver Foundation - Never returns value

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ms-solver-foundation

I need to port an excel spreadsheet that uses the solver plugin to an ASP.NET c# site, I'm using the Solver Foundation 3.1 to no avail.

The equation is iterative, and two conditions need to be met in order to determine the two decision values.

The two decision values on the spreadsheet are set to 1

```
Ng = 1
Nv = 1
```

Then the goal is to find the MAX of Formula1 when the following conditions are met:

```
Decision 1: Formula1 = _na
Decision 2: Formula2 = Formula3
```

All formulas use Ng and Nv, hitting solve changes Ng and Nv to satisfy each equation, it takes and average of 22 iterations on the spreadsheet.

I've implemented it in c# as follows:

```
 public class FluxSolver
    {
        public FluxSolver(double _na, double _ygo, double _k, double _alpha, double _inletVoidFraction)
        {
            var solver = SolverContext.GetContext();
            solver.ClearModel();

            var model = solver.CreateModel();

            var decisionNG = new Decision(Domain.RealNonnegative, "NG");
            var decisionNV = new Decision(Domain.RealNonnegative, "NV");

            model.AddDecision(decisionNG);
            model.AddDecision(decisionNV);

            Term formula1 = (_ygo * decisionNG) + ((1 - _ygo) * decisionNV);

            model.AddGoal("Goal", GoalKind.Maximize, formula1);

            model.AddConstraint("Constraint1", ((_inletVoidFraction / _k) * (1 / decisionNG)) == (_alpha * ((1 / decisionNV) - 1)));
            model.AddConstraint("Constraint2", ( _ygo * decisionNG) + ((1 - _ygo) * decisionNV) == _na);

            var solution = solver.Solve();

            NV = decisionNV.GetDouble();
            NG = decisionNG.GetDouble();
            Quality = solution.Quality.ToString();

        }

        public double NG { get; set; }
        public double NV { get; set; }
        public string Quality { get; set; }
    }
```

I've been at it for 3 days now and still not making any progress, the solver just loads and and disappears, never times out, doesn't return the values etc. Is there something fundamentally wrong in my code?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with your implementation of the `FluxSolver` class, I have tried it unmodified and it returns a solution on the instant. (My in parameters were *1, 1, 1, 1, and 0.5*.)  I notice that the decision variables are denominators in divisions; maybe you should set the feasible variable ranges to `Domain.RealRange(EPS, Rational.PositiveInfinity)` (where `EPS` is a sufficiently small positive value) instead of `Domain.RealNonnegative`.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson thank you for your help, sorry I forgot to mention that on init the values being passed are usually to the 5th decimal place like this example: FluxSolver massflux = new FluxSolver(0.10330, 0.46954, 1, 2.21680, 0.88944); I've tried setting the bounds as you mentioned to be between 0 and 1 (as the excel spreadsheet returns values for this example as Ng = 0.0614 and Nv = 0.14033)

Comment: I have a feeling its because the excel spreadsheet rounds the number to the 5th decimal when comparing the constraints, where as mine would be to the nth which is why it never matches! How would I round the decimal places? Math.Round isn't accepted in the constraints...

Comment: Most of the `Math` functions have their MSF counterparts in `Model`, e.g. `Model.Abs`, `Model.Sin` etc. (not `Model.Round` though). Maybe you can reformulate your problem using these functions.